# "They survived the journey" is journey a direct object?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, direct-objects

In the sentence:

> "There was no guarantee that the travelers would survive the journey."

Would "the journey" be considered a direct object, or what would it be?

In this sentence nothing seems to be being done to the journey by the travelers. *The journey* is not the recipient of some kind of "surviving" action.

Here is the top definition of *direct object* if you [Google it](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=direct+object&oq=direct+object&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3j69i60.2646j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

> - A direct object is a noun or pronoun that receives the action of a verb or shows the result of the action. It answers the question "What?" or "Whom?" after an action verb. An action verb with a direct object is called a transitive verb.

This seems to be the general description of direct objects. Here's the next definition from the grammar site [Daily Grammar](http://www.dailygrammar.com/Lesson-109-Direct-Object.htm):

> - A direct object receives the action performed by the subject. The verb used with a direct object is always an action verb. Another way of saying it is that the subject does the verb to the direct object. Example: The car hit the tree. To find the direct object, say the subject and verb followed by whom or what. The car hit whom or what? Tree answers the question so tree is the direct object.

Comment: According to this dictionary, 'survive' can be a transitive verb and so 'journey' would be the direct object. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/survive

Comment: This is by no means trivial. With a simplistic definition of transitivity / direct objects, 'the journey' here is a (sometimes called syntactic...) direct object. But where would people draw the line with _John survived the ordeal / John survived the journey / John survived the first year of teaching / John survived another year / John survived three days underwater_ ? Perhaps the passivisability test identifies the last two  examples here as not being transitive usages?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Any chance of your reopen vote then, given that I spent a while editing it to make the problem clearer?

Comment: The question needs to be re-edited to correct the far too prescriptive 'A direct object is a noun or pronoun that receives the action of a verb or shows the result of the action.' // 'The verb used with a direct object is always an action verb. ' This begs the question here.

Comment: You ask " Who survived what?", so "the journey" is a direct object. The general definition "action form subject directed to direct object" is not optimal in all cases.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth It was necessary, unfortunately, to show why the OP might be doubtful about why *the journey* was a direct object. Otherwise, it was going to remain closed ... That drivel in those definitions there is unfortunately often repeated in the pages here ...